# Move Magento currency switcher to the left of the product price

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, switcher

My store runs on Magento 1.942

I want to move the currency switcher from the top to the left of the product price. I tried searching on google for a long time and couldn't find a way. Please help me? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 header currency drop-down shown from file `app/design/frontend/THEME/default/layout/directory.xml`

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency_switcher" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

so if you want to show that in product view page than just put below block in `app/design/frontend/THEME/default/layout/catalog.xml` file as (add block in product.info block)

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency_switcher" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

now call this block in phtml file where you want to show in product view page `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` as `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher');?>`